# Time dilation if earth was stationary

Tags: relativity, time-dilation

Being on earth, we are constantly flying through space at incredible speeds. We revolve around a sun in a system that revolves around the center of the galaxy that is hurling itself through space. Looking at the equation for time dilation that is usually used: $T=T' \sqrt{1-\frac{V^2}{C^2}}$ I came up with a question: What if we weren't? There must be a format of the equation that allows us to determine how much 'faster' time would be elapsing if we truly had a velocity of 0.

Comment: 'if we truly had a velocity of 0'... the point of SRT is that velocities are *relative*.

Answer (score 4):

There is no true velocity in special relativity, only relative velocity between two different frames.

I think part of the confusion is in the interpretation of phrases like "time slows down." Time never slows down for you according to your own watch.

Consider Earth's motion around the Sun at $30\ \mathrm{km/s}$, $0.01\%$ the speed of light. As far as someone at rest compared to the Sun is concerned, we appear to be slowed down. That is, only $999{,}999{,}995$ Earth-seconds pass for every $1{,}000{,}000{,}000$ Sun-seconds. But this doesn't mean Earth-seconds are somehow slower than "real" seconds. And in fact the situation is perfectly symmetric: to me on Earth I will observe a Sun-person's watch tick $999{,}999{,}995$ times over the time it takes my watch to tick $1{,}000{,}000{,}000$ times.

As far as relativity is concerned, all we have to do is be consistent: whenever we mention a time (or location) we have to be clear which observer that is according to. And in fact this is *all* we can do -- there is no other definition of time independent of some observer.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is always relative. So if the Earth could be considered stationary, and yet some other bodies were moving, the Earth would be again in motion wrt. these bodies. Therefore you would have time dilatation again.

In Einstein's SR Theory there is no time dilatation only if everything in the Universe is still.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris White points out velocity (and speed) is relative, but I'll add a caveat that the Universe does have a 'special' set of local frames of reference, these are the frames in which the CMB (cosmic microwave background) appears at it's most isotropic (the same in all directions) and are called comoving frames. The speed of an object relative to it's local comoving frame is called it's peculiar speed and the Earth's peculiar speed  is approximately 360 km/s.

The comoving frame of reference also has the property that it maximizes the time since the big bang, or in other words observers who stay at rest relative to the CMB experience the longest possible age of the Universe compared to any other nearby observes. If the age of the Universe is 13.8 billion years (for our local comoving observer) and we had a constant* peculiar speed of 360 km/s since the big bang then we would've experienced 10,000 years less than 13.8 billion years since the big bang.

*NB peculiar speed in fact doesn't stay constant due to various factors and actually cosmological expansion itself has a slowing effect on peculiar velocities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect evidence you can give that either you are moving or at rest becouse there is nither absolute rest nor absolute motion.I give an example, if you say that i am really at rest, then an observer on another planet moving with velocity v would measure your velocity equal to his own velocity, considering himself at rest, this is called relative velocity and in the time dialation equation at the place of v, you put your velocity relative to another observer. If you have some velocity relative to him, he will measure greater time interval between any two events occuring in your frame of reference. If you have no velocity relative to him i.e v relative is 0 then he will measure equal to the time you measure between any two events occuring in your reference frame and vise versa.